# Mailing list history

Tags: history

in these days I'm doing research about the history of the mailing lists. Someone can suggest me interesting "Papers" or Article on the web in order to learn much about history and principal use of this service?

Comment: I don't think this is ontopic here; it does not seem to be about computer *science*. I'm not sure where to send you, though; maybe [SU] since mailing lists used to be super-user tools? Anyway, community votes, please!

Comment: It's borderline, but I think there's no harm in tangible CS questions (e.g., teaching CS or history of CS). I'm not sure you you will see good answers here, though. Maybe better at [history.se].